# Find width of edge in opencv which i am getting from sobel function

Tags: c++, opencv, blurry

[image]
I want to find width of edge which i m getting from sobel. But i don't know how to find width of this edges. Anyone can help me to figure out this?

Comment: Could you please provide examples of images?

Comment: What do you mean by edge that you are getting from sobel?? do you mean the length of the lines???

Comment: Not length.I want to find width of edge/line.